# Waterline: Find by value in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, sails.js, waterline

I have a nested `address` attribute in one of my models.

```
attributes: {
  address: {
    type: 'json'
  }
}
```

How can I find model instances located i.e. the same city.
I tried several queries:

```
Model.find({ "address.city": city })
Model.find({ address: { contains: city }})
```

But none seem to work for. Any ideas on how to properly formulate this query?

Answer (score 0):

For sure, a mongo native call powered by Warerline works: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native

Then the query object in your first attempt should work. Beware that then the mongodb documentation is the leading over the waterline one regarding query parameters. E.g. you need to cast ObjectId on id queries before using them in a native query.

Comment: In my testing I am using the `sails-memory` instead of the `sails-mongo` adapter. Native seems to work only with MongoDB. Maybe I just have add another "Address" model and work with a one-to-one or a one-way relation instead.

Comment: For sure, native calls only work for the sails-mongo adapter. That’s why I assumed Mongodb here in the first place